# Is there a way to disable the Guard animation?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When you use the Guardian's  ability named Guard, it protects other characters. It is very useful in many situations. However, is there a way to disable the animation where there is a shield around the guarded character? It is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not.  The only way to remove the animation is for the effect itself to be removed (the recipient clicking off the buff/dying, or the tank turning off the guard/guarding someone else/dying).